# Finding $~x~ y~$and $~z~$

Tags: percentages

This is probably too simple of a question for the geniuses here but I can't wrap my head around this backwards algebra logic. I need to know the values of $x$ $y$ and $z$ according to the following data:

$x+y-z=300$

$y$ is $23\%$ of $x$

$z$ is $25\%$ of $x$

I am completely stumped :|

Comment: Write $y=0.23x$ and $z=0.25x$, and replace in the first equation. Then solve for $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=0.23x$

$z=0.25x$

$x+0.23x-0.25x=300$

$0.98x=300$

$x=\dfrac{300}{0.98}\approx306.122$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you, i understand now, i'll try to fit this into the spreadsheet ^^

Comment: You saved me, i fit this into my spreadsheet formula as =B8/(1+C5-C6)where C5 is 23% and C6 is 25% :D

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is $23\%$ of $x$, then $y\displaystyle =\frac{23}{100}\times x$, which means $y=0.23x$. Similarly, $z=0.25x$.

Then, you have the equation $x+0.23x-0.25x=300$.

Can you proceed from there?

Comment: Yes, as Tanner answered, it's $1x+0.23x-0.25x=300$, which turns into $0.98x=300$, which turns into $x=300/0.98$